# ORMLite (Android) Please, help me drafting a request

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

Really need your help in drafting a request to [ORMlite](http://ormlite.com/) (Android).

There are sql queries (NamedQuery):

1. `select m.contact.stringId, count(m.contact.stringId) from MessageEntityImpl m where m.status = MessageStatus.NEW group by m.contact.stringId"`
2. `SELECT m.chat_id, c.stringid, c.fullname, m.message, Max(posted) as postDate from messageentity m inner join (select chat_id, MAX(posted) max_posted from messageentity group by chat_id) max_posted_date ON m.chat_id = max_posted_date.chat_id and posted = max_posted_date.max_posted inner join contactentity c on c.ID = m.contact_id group by m.chat_id, c.stringid, c.fullname, m.message order by postDate desc`

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off issuing a raw query to get the results back (as `GenericRawResults<T>`) and then traversing through the container to get the your required results. Here's an example -

```
String sql = "select m.contact.stringId from MessageEntityImpl m where m.status = MessageStatus.NEW group by m.contact.stringId";

ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<>();

try
{
    GenericRawResults<String[]> grr = getDao().queryRaw(sql);
    List<String[]> results = grr.getResults();
    for (String[] outArray : results)
        id.add (outArray[0]);
}
catch (SQLException sqle)
{
    sqle.printStackTrace();
}
```

getDao() can be a `BaseDaoImpl<T,ID>`.